# Extjs Routers pass multiple parameters

Tags: extjs, routes

I need to pass three parameters in the Routes we use in Extjs , i tried giving like below but its not working , what would be the issue.

```
routes  : {
        ':id:subid:pagetype': {
            action: 'renderPage'
        }
    }
```

and this is where i initiate the Route Call.

```
callRouter: function(field) {
   if(!Ext.isEmpty(field)){
        this.redirectTo(field.id+':'+field.subId+':'+field.pageType);
   }
}
```

this is the action method i use

```
navigatePage: function(id,subid,pagetype) {}
```

Comment: Have you tried `':id/:subid/:pagetype'` and `this.redirect(field.id+'/'+field.subId+'/'+field.pageType)`?

Comment: @CD.. Thanks a lot it worked :)

Comment: Great, I've added it as an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set the route as:

```
':id/:subid/:pagetype'
```

And then use:

```
this.redirect(field.id+'/'+field.subId+'/'+field.pageType);
```